# Question about New releases and what to do with them

Tags: 8

CAVEAT - I am NOT a technical person - the instructions on the Drupal site make no sense to me.

So someone built a site for me using Drupal, its hosted via Domain.com 
I can go in and edit pages
but I keep getting emails about New Releases
"There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure
the security of your server, you should update immediately!"

But I'm not sure what to do with the updates - do I just save the downloads to my PC even though the site is being hosted? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Michele

Comment: You are likely to get downvotes for this questions since you haven't checked drupal.org for documentation about updating. If you did and didn't understand the instructions, you should expand the question. I decided to answer with obvious links to the docs (without downvoting the question).

Comment: You are in a difficult situation as a non technical person. I would strongly recommend to get yourself some technical help to walk you through this fast and secure. Checkout developers or agencies in your area, there should be plenty.

Comment: Drupal, like any other platform, needs a technical person on the team to perform routine or security upgrades over time. You may want to reach out to local companies who can do this work for you for a reasonable price.

Answer (score 2):

How to manually update your Drupal 8 installation is explained several places - see

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-manually or
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/security-update-core.html or
- the file `UPDATE.txt` which is part of the Drupal zip/tar-ball you have downloaded.

PS! If you are familiar with the Command Line and have shell access on Domain.com, you might consider using [Composer for updating](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer).

Answer (score -1):

For update your Drupal and its modules go to the below URL:
http(or https)://YOURSITENAME/admin/reports/updates/update

Comment: I'd advise against this.